# Selenium WebDriver - Do Page Scrolling and Click multiple checks on the page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dears all,

Need help on the below scenario!

**Scenario:** - Login to amazon website and after successful login, I am searching for samsung galaxy phone and once the search results are displayed on the page, I need to narrow down the search results by choosing the below check boxes from the left side of the page which requires scrolling

- Samsung
- Android
- Battery - 3000 to 3999 MAH
- Screen - 5.5 inch and above
- Ram - 4GB more
- Low price = 25000
- High price = 300000

My code (implementing POM) below

**Issue** - This code is checking samsung but when it goes to check android, I get the message -

> Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it
>   was looked up Command duration or timeout: 30.13 seconds

Please advise me how do I achieve the scrolling part and do all the selects which I have mentioned. Thanks for helping in advance!!

**Code**

```
public class Amazon_Samsung_Galaxy_Search 
{
    WebDriver driver;

    public Amazon_Samsung_Galaxy_Search(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;

    }

    @FindBy (xpath = ".//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']") WebElement Product_Search;
    @FindBy (xpath = "//input[@class='nav-input'][@type='submit']") WebElement Search_Click;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']") WebElement Android_Check;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//*[@id='ref_3837712031']//img[@alt='Samsung']") WebElement Samsung_Check;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//*[@id='ref_8561098031']//img[@alt='3000 - 3999 mAh']") WebElement Battery_Check;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//*[@id='ref_6631751031']//img[@alt='5.5 Inches & Above']") WebElement Screen_Check;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//*[@id='ref_8561129031']//img[@alt='4 GB & More']") WebElement Ram_Check;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//input[@id='low-price']") WebElement Low_Price;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//input[@id='high-price']") WebElement High_Price;
    @FindBy (xpath = "//input[@class='leftNavGoBtn']") WebElement GO_Button;
    @FindBy (xpath = ".//span[@id='quartsPagelet']") WebElement Search_Result;

    public void Search_Samsung_Galaxy()
    {
        Product_Search.sendKeys("Samsung Galaxy");
        Search_Click.click();

        Samsung_Check.click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']")));

        Coordinates cor = ((Locatable)Android_Check).getCoordinates();
        cor.inViewPort();

        Android_Check.click();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It occurs due to [`Stale Element Reference Exception`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp).

*The most frequent cause of this is that page that the element was part of has been refreshed, or the user has navigated away to another page. A less common, but still common cause is where a JS library has deleted an element and replaced it with one with the same ID or attributes. In this case, although the replacement elements may look identical they are different; the driver has no way to determine that the replacements are actually what's expected.*

In your case you have already stored `Android_Check`, So after clicking `Samsung_Check.click();` the page has changed, for this reason selenium could not found `Android_Check` in the cache, `Android_Check` needs to be refresh again, you should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Android_Check = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']")));

Coordinates cor = ((Locatable)Android_Check).getCoordinates();
cor.inViewPort();

Android_Check.click();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Hi Saurabh..I tried making the changes what you said above but I still get the message - Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 30.08 seconds


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  Android_Check = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']")));
  
  Coordinates cor = ((Locatable)Android_Check).getCoordinates();
  cor.inViewPort();

Comment: @Bimlesh create new refrence of `Android_Check` like as :- `WebElement androidCheck = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1‌​485076031']//img[@alt='Android']")));Coordinates cor = ((Locatable)androidCheck).getCoordinates();
cor.inViewPort();

androidCheck.click();`..and let me knwo the result

Comment: @Surabh - tried making the changes but still the same response --Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Command duration or timeout: 30.08 seconds             WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement AndroidCheck = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']")));
  
  Coordinates cor = ((Locatable)AndroidCheck).getCoordinates();
  cor.inViewPort(); AndroidCheck.click();

Comment: @Bimlesh could you tell me in which line are you getting the exception??

Comment: Saurabh :- at this line WebElement AndroidCheck = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_1485076031']//img[@alt='Android']"))); The code is clicking "Samsung" first and then when it comes to selecting "Android" - I am getting this exception.